# Swift: how to switch back to previous UITableViewController without adding a segue

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, segue

In my iOS app I would like that, after a positive result, the screen to switch back to the previous screen. In my case I would switch back from a UITableViewController to another UITableViewController. I have tried with:

```
self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion:nil)
```

but it doesn't work, nothing appears.
I have also tried with:

```
let mainStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle())
let vc : UITableViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Tasks") as UITableViewController
self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

but I get "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" in the method viewWillAppear() in:

```
self.navigationController!.editButtonItem().title = "Modifica"
```

I with I could avoid add another reverse segue from the interface builder and then perform performSegueWithIdentifier(). Isn't there a faster way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using a `UINavigationController`? If so, you just call `navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)` to go to the previous screen.

If you aren't using a `UINavigationController`, you can call `dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)` to achieve the same result.

In both cases, you don't need to use `self` as it is already implied.

Comment: Ok, it works perfectly with navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true) but I am forced to use "self": XCode requires me to because I am inside a closure handling a response from a database done by NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL()

Comment: Ah, in that case, yes, you need self.